# Shape or point pattern

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, autocad

Is it possible to draw one shapeline or one point and repeat it in a specific direction with a specific distance for a specific amount? Like the pattern function in AutoCAD? I'm working with QGIS.

An application example, to digitalize the gouges on a field.

Comment: For those who know QGIS, but not AutoCAD: can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Are you going to use this for visualization only or do you need to actual geometries for something?

Comment: To clarify, you are referring to the Offset tool in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lines, in the Processing Toolbox you can use the `Vector creation > Array of offset (parallel) lines` tool.

Comment: Thank you Teddy, this is exactly what im looking for :)